# Issues with "collect()" or "take(n)" on MB-sized data on spark

Tags: apache-spark

We are a group of people working with spark (spark 2.1.0 standalone
with 2 workers; the programming is done in scala and everything is
running inside several dockers). We encountered a problem that make
"collect" or "take(n)" go very slow once when the collected data hits
some size cap.

We encountered the problem on several occasions but we have boiled
down the problem to a simple example: it reads a file (either from
local filesystem or from hdfs; we tested both) and then collect the
result. It works fine until a certain size of file (around 2 MB) and
then it is very slow (and around 3 MB it completely breaks). If it
doesn't collect (e.g. it just does a saveAsTextFile) the setup can
deal with files as large as 200 GB. We have tested increasing the
driver memory tenfold (from 2GB of RAM to 20GB of RAM) but it doesn't
solve the issue; in fact our tests show that our little experiment
slows at the very same size of file regardless of how much RAM we give
to the driver or the workers.

I have summed up my experiment here: https://pastebin.com/raw/6yXztq0H

In this experiment the program reads a file "s" and "take(n)" with "n"
gradually increasing. As the timestamped output shows, it work almost
instantly for "n≤104145" (it actually varies just a little despite large changes in setup) and then it is quite slow. For large "n" (see
second run) the driver crashes with a "TaskResultLost" error. The last
experiment (third run) shows that this does not seem to be a memory
problem (and that seems logical since the file is relatively small,
around 2 MB).

(It is not shown in the experiment but we also played with
SPARK_DAEMON_MEM but it doesn't seem to change anything.)

Has anybody ever had the same problem? Has anybody an idea to help us search further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we managed to get a hold of what is going on. Here is a description of the problem for future references:

1. When the collected data size is large enough, the driver will interact directly with the executors instead of going through the master; that is why our problem only appear after a certain size.
2. There was a network issue in our setup between some of the executors and the driver that makes some connections fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried increasing spark.driver.memory, try increasing spark.driver.maxResultSize

Comment: Thank you, I tested varying this parameter and it doesn't seem to change anything :s https://pastebin.com/raw/qHVK0E1S